# ImageView Keeps coming to the front

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app using Xcode. When I am in the editing menu everything looks fine I am able to see the textfields and buttons however when I run the app on the simulator the image I have for the background comes to the front and hides everything else. Is there anyway to fix the background to the back and make it never come forward?

If you post any code could you please do it using SWIFT

[image]

[image]

Comment: plz post your storyboard along with the menu editor opened.

Comment: @SahebRoy I have added pictures

Comment: look at debug hierarchy , and see what is behind the image view @user278063

Comment: there could be two things happenning here. There may be a chance of wrong constraints which is pushing or shrinking the all the elements on the image view!!! Or you actually do something to the imageview to bring it front !!! Show us the view hierarchy and also the code if u have any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder check the left sidebar and you will see the view hierarchy.

Just add your view as normal, then drag it up the view hierarchy to the top of the list in 'View' and it will be at the bottom of the stack.

**Alternatively**, Select the view in the Interface Builder, and then do **Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Back**

[image: Send ImageView To Back]